# Reading ORC File using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I'm trying to read ORC File compressed using SNAPPY via MapReduce. My intent is just to leverage IdentityMapper, essentially to merge small files. However, I get `NullPointerException` on doing so. I can see from the log that schema is being inferred, do I still need to set the schema for the output file from mapper ?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();


    Job job = new Job(conf, "test");

    job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
     conf.set("orc.compress", "SNAPPY");
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Writable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(OrcInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(OrcOutputFormat.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);


    String source = args[0];
    String target = args[1];

    FileInputFormat.setInputPath(job, new Path(source))
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(target));

    boolean result = job.waitForCompletion(true);

    System.exit(result ? 0 : 1);
}
```

> Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.(WriterImpl.java:178) at
>   org.apache.orc.OrcFile.createWriter(OrcFile.java:559) at
>   org.apache.orc.mapreduce.OrcOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(OrcOutputFormat.java:55)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:644)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

Comment: **1.** Your question is about "reading" but the error occurs in `WriterImpl` => ???  **2.** Did you consider using Hive -- it can run two different kinds of "ORC merge", i.e. ALTER COMPACT will just concatenate the existing stripes into fewer files, and INSERT SELECT *(plus appropriate settings for the merge-small-files properties)* will copy the original data in different files, with different settings (e.g. compression)

Comment: Yes, I'm encountering errors in WriterImpl. Hive  is an not an option for me, I need to handle files independent of partition/table.

Comment: What do you mean by "independant"? If you mean that the files are in a HDFS directory that is not mapped to a Hive table, then you can just declare an EXTERNAL TABLE on that dir, run some queries, then drop the table.

Comment: The files are in a HDFS dir, but I need operate on data (files) based on file names. A directory/partition would have N number of files, I'm having to do operations on specific files for performance reasons

Comment: Ever used the Hive pseudo-column `INPUT__FILE__NAME` (with two _ each time)?

Comment: I haven't before. How does it work ? Full hdfs path supported ? Or it can just add as a filename filter on a query by partition per se ?